# Add row in data frame automatically

Tags: python, dataframe

Could someone tell me how to Add rows in this dataframe automatically?
I have a data frame df :

```
                                   frequency
enrollment_id event      days           
1             access     2             3
                         7             8
                         9             4
                         10            3
                         12            2
                         15           21
                         18            4
                         19            8
                         20           20
                         22           16
                         23            2
                         28            2
                         29           14
              navigate   2             1
                         7             4
                         9             1
                         10            3
                         11            1
                         12            1
                         15            5
                         18            1
                         19            1
                         22            3
                         23            1
                         28            1
                         29            2
              page_close 2             1
                         7             6
                         9             2
                         10            3
...                                  ...
200881        navigate   28            1
200882        discussion 28            4
              navigate   28            4
200883        access     28            2
              navigate   28            2
              page_close 28            1
200885        navigate   21            1
200887        access     21            3
              navigate   21            2
              page_close 21            1
              video      21            1
200888        access     21            2
              discussion 21            1
              navigate   21            5
              page_close 21            1
              video      21            1
              wiki       21            1
200889        navigate   21            1
200893        navigate   21            2
200895        navigate   21            1
200896        navigate   21            1
200897        navigate   21            1
200898        navigate   21            1
200900        navigate   21            1
200901        access     21            3
              navigate   21            2
              page_close 21            2
              video      21            1
200904        navigate   21            1
200905        navigate   21            1
```

This df has 3 index: 1. event 2. days 3. enrollment_id 
and only one column `frequency`

1. event has 7 different `value` like : `access`, `remove` etc.
2. days has 30 different `vaule` `0 - 29` (not every event has `0 - 29`. some event just has for example `0`, `1`, `4`.)
3. `enrollment_id` has a lot of different `value` (maybe `100000`). Same, not each days has all `enrollment_id`.
   My question is : How can I add all lost rows?

For example :   If I have this

```
                                     frequency
enrollment_id event      days           
1             access     2             3
                         7             8
```

I need to add rows for

```
                               frequency
enrollment_id event      days           
1             access     0             0
                         1             0
                         3             0
                         4             0
                         5             0
                         6             0
                         ...           ...
                         29            0
```

and I need to add rows for `0` with all other `enrollment_id` and `frequency 0`
and and all rows for `access` with`0days - 29days` and `enrollment_id` from `1 - max`

I really want to get this answer. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Please add data sample and desired output like text, [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please give example of data and how you would like to process it to clarify what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

If need add mising days only to last level `days` use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df['frequency'].unstack()
                    .reindex(columns=list(range(30)), fill_value=0)
                    .stack()
                    .to_frame('frequency')
```

If need add all combination of all levels:

Use  by new `MultiIndex` created by [`from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
#get all unique values of all levels
a = df.index.get_level_values('enrollment_id').unique()
b = df.index.get_level_values('event').unique()
c = df.index.get_level_values('days').unique()
```

Or you can use your values in lists like:

```
a = ['access', 'remove']
b = range(1, df.index.get_level_values('event').max() + 1)
c = range(30)

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b,c], names=df.index.names)

#for missing values add 0
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You really give me too much inspiration. I have already fixed the problem. Best regards!